# sfGuardPlugin session: how to reuse it with wget -- or map SID to sfGuardUser

Tags: session, authentication, cookies, symfony1, wget

Recently I was asked to add an XML API to one of the Symfony modules in my project. I did it, and it works well. For authentication, we use `sfGuardPlugin`. Symfony version is 1.3.11. Using Propel, not Doctrine.

The most recent request to me is this:

1. We will embed a Flash game into the website.
2. The Flash will do requests to the XML API.
3. The guy who is coding the Flash application says that it doesn't share cookies with the browser.
4. We want the Flash to be able to reuse the session of the currently logged in user (we won't allow to be even shown if no user is logged in).

**I did try this would-be solution:** (taken from other SO articles and various Google search results)

1. I was told that the Symfony session resides in the `symfony` cookie.
2. I was told that if I copy this value in another client (in my case, `wget`) and do `session_id("stolen_session_id")` I will be able to duplicate the session, have the same user logged in, etc.
3. This turned out to be wrong. Say my cookie symfony had the "blabla" value. I did this: `wget --post-data='session_id=blabla' X.X.X.X:NN/api/bla.xml -O-`. My server PHP code parses this POST parameter and feeds it to `session_id` function. It then reported in the logs that the `session_id('blabla')` was returning `1`. However, calling `$this->getUser()->getGuardUser()` returns `null`.

**I need a way to map a passed `session_id` to a valid `sfGuardUser`.** Or find an alternative way of reusing a session which already exists.

Suppose I have full access to the cookies. I want to know which one of them (or all of them?) to duplicate in order to achieve this.

BTW, I am seeing in my Chrome dev tools that the `symfony` cookie is of a session type. So it's no wonder at all as to why my method doesn't work, but I am little lost as to how do I do this in Symfony, while using the `sfGuardPlugin`.

I do realize this is not one of the most informed questions, but ditto, I just need help.

Thanks for your time.

(Dimitar P.)

*Oops, forgot to mention which cookies I see on my domain*:

- symfony
- sfRemember
- __utma
- __utmb
- __utmc
- __utmz

I am guessing the last four are for Google Analytics, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't want to do this, but I was unable to find other alternatives:

`$ wget --header='Cookie: symfony=blabla' X.X.X.X:NN/api/bla.xml -O-`

I wanted my XML API to be REST, but evidently, Symfony doesn't allow authenticated requests other way than using cookies (and to enable the session ID to be always included in the URL is not an option **at all**).

Still, if somebody shows up with a fully REST alternative, I will upvote his/her answer.

Comment: Alright people of SO, I waited long enough for somebody to answer the same as me and get his 15 rep, but since nobody showed up, I will accept my answer. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You will need some way of specifying which user is executing the (wget) request. And PHP sessions use a session ID by default.

A common way to do this is token-based authentication. The most common way to achieve this is OAuth, which has a lot of default libraries (both for Symfony and for your API consumers).

If you're the only one using this API, you can also create a custom token (random sha1 string) per user per session (you can store this somewhere in your database). Now you would create something like ` wget X.X.X.X:NN/api/bla.xml?token=asdfhdsfhf

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Sadly I am working with legacy software. Can't do much changes.